# Form adding new user missing 1 required positional argument in Django

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I created a form to add a new user, but it throws an error `_wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`.

This is the form:

```
class NewEmployee(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

And this is my view:

```
@login_required(login_url='./accounts/login/')
def NewEmployee(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewEmployee(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('backend')
    else:
        form = NewEmployee()
    return render(request, 'backend/new_employee.html', {'form': form})
```

**EDIT**

The traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/dash/funcionario/novo/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.1
Installed Applications:
['backend',
 'frontend',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utilizador\Envs\navioenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Utilizador\Envs\navioenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Utilizador\Envs\navioenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utilizador\Envs\navioenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\GitHub\navio\backend\views.py", line 36, in NewEmployee
    form = NewEmployee()

Exception Type: TypeError at /dash/funcionario/novo/
Exception Value: _wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Comment: please post the full traceback.

Comment: Can we see the user model please ?

Comment: @Stéphane it's the django User model, not a custom one.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers just added it

Comment: Apparently it was the fact that `def NewEmployee` wasn't all lowercase.

Comment: @JoãodeSousa More likely the fact that you had called both your view and model the same thing.

Comment: @FiddleStix lowercase and uppercase are understood as being different?

Comment: They are indeed.  Your view is a function so the python convention would be `def new_employee(request):` or `def new_employee_view(request)`.

Comment: Ok, that's great! Do you want make an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @FiddleStix well spotted - I should have seen this too xD

Comment: @JoãodeSousa yes Python is case-sensitive (like most languages FWIW). If you don't know this I kindly but very strongly suggest you stop your project for a couple days and [do the full official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) - it will save you a lot of time and frustration.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks for the suggestion! I will take a look!